# VisualVM profiling hangs while instrumenting classes

Tags: java, profiler, visualvm

I have a strange behavior while trying to profile a Java Application with VisualVm.

> Hostsystem = SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10
>
> Java `JDK` (same is running `VisualVM` and Application to profile) = jdk1.8.0_40 64bit

Profiling other applications (e.g. Tomcat) running on the host with the same `JDK` do not have this Problem.

Profiling my Application on Windows (running from Eclipse) also works fine.

After starting the profiling the log reads the following lines:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.profiler]: Profiler Attach
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.profiler]: Profiler Settings
*** Profiler warning (Thu Oct 08 14:36:10 CEST 2015): class java/lang /UNIXProcess$$Lambda$9/1156856411, ldr = 0 not found anywhere
*** Profiler warning (Thu Oct 08 14:36:10 CEST 2015): class java/lang/invoke/LambdaForm$DMH/1131480230, ldr = 0 not found anywhere
*** Profiler warning (Thu Oct 08 14:36:10 CEST 2015): class java/lang/invoke/LambdaForm$MH/1901642836, ldr = 0 not found anywhere
*** Profiler warning (Thu Oct 08 14:36:10 CEST 2015): class java/lang
... and so on, stopping after 60 lines with similar output ...
```

My Application has the following `JVM` Parameters (BTW. I read at some other point, that there are problems with setting tmp Dir, but removing the parameter doesn't help either)

```
-XX:-UseLWPSynchronization
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<removed>
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin
-Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/global/ECAS_TESTAS/ecastest/ecas/conf/management.properties
-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout=180000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=600000
-verbose:gc
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,ecas/logik/ELogikKomponentenVersion.doBerechnen
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/global/ECAS_TESTAS/ecastest/ecas/tmp
-XX:NewSize=2100m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=20
-Xms10000m
-Xmx10000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=120m
```

Here you find a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjR4Y.png) showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research with sending sigterm (kill -3 pid) to produce stacktrace I found out, that visualvm was still parsing possible classes. 
After that, I noticed that for this process "." was in classpath. So I removed it. Now it works as expected.