# Nashorn Javascript engine using cpu by loading classes after a minute?

Tags: javascript, java, performance, nashorn

Using Java8u60, nashorn

The objective is to have approx 2000 function-objects interact with each their own API object every 500 msec. Each script being approx 5 to 20 lines of code.

What i see is that after the initial burst of CPU usage used for compiling the script it is running quite nicely. But after approximately a minute, there is another burst of CPU usage and a massive amount of classes are being loaded.

I would like to know why this is happening (because it was already compiled right?), and what ways there are to influence this phenomenon.

Below, the effect as seen by using JvisualVM.
*Initially:*
[image: initial_running_and_compile]

*After a minute approx 10000 classes are loaded. See the cpu usage and spike in right-bottom corner graph:*
[image: running_a_minute_and_classesloaded]

Some details:
Each function-object has its own `SimpleScriptContext`.
I use `Swingworkers` to firstly compile and on next invocations execute the compiled function.
I have a `ScriptEngine` instance per thread (`Swingworkers` use a pool of 10 threads hardcoded in JDK) in the hope that compiling doesn't block other threads.
Each `SwingWorker` instance executes a single `CompiledScript` for all function-objects having the same script-text only once and then exits.(There are approx 30 unique scripts.)
These SwingWorkers are instantiated and executed every 500msec.
This is the code i use for executing a function-object:

```
/* 
 * test for script change, if so, recompile 
 */
if (e.cCompiledScript == null) {
  /* compile once, but don't when an error is not cleared */
  if (runner.cErrorString == null) {
    e.initCompiledScript(runner.getScript());
  }
} else {
  /* run the CompiledScript in the (shared)engine with the provided private context */
  e.cCompiledScript.eval(runner.getScriptContext());
}
```

Comment: What classes are being loaded after a minute? Check with `-XX:+TraceClassLoading`.

Comment: Initially it shows a lot of lines contianing  
`[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/3175035 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]`
, but at the peak in classes being loaded it says mostly BMH
`Profiler Agent Warning: JVMTI classLoadHook: class name is null.
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/19678099 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/586680 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/27194906 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VisualVM profiling hangs while instrumenting classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016411/visualvm-profiling-hangs-while-instrumenting-classes)